# Data Source For Oracle

Tags: oracle10g, datasource

I am using 64-bit version of windows 7. The only option I have in it, for creating Data SOurce is for Microsoft SQL server 2005. Hence, I am not in position to create ODBC for oracle. Is there any other way by which I can create the ODBC Data Source. I need the same for JDBC. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Data Source for Oracle in 64 Bit windows operating system, go to

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
```

And use odbcad32.exe file. Double click it and the option to make dsn will come, even for Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Just install the Oracle Instant Client from the Oracle [website](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html).